# php mysql display by views

Tags: php, mysql

thanks for loking.

i have 3 tables

**books, book_category, book_click**.

**books table**
book_id,
url,
title,
img,
short_desc,
featured,
enable

**book_category table**
book_id, category_id

**book_clicks table**
site_id, time, views

i like to get data from **books** table by view **SUMS** but this only returns one result

```
SELECT  books.book_id, url, title, short_desc, img, featured, SUM(views) as total_views
 FROM  books,book_category,book_click  WHERE  enable=1 AND category_id=7
AND books.book_id=book_category.book_id
ORDER BY  strong texttotal_views DESC
```

Comment: You'll have to post the schema, because, to me at least, the query means nothing without the table structure.

Comment: You have nothing to link the views with the books themselves.  How do you know which entry in the book_clicks table goes to which book?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the mysql WITH ROLLUP

**UPDATE**

After reading your quesion again it might be as simple as adding `GROUP BY books.book_id`

```
SELECT  books.book_id, url, title, short_desc, img, featured, SUM(views) as total_views
 FROM  books,book_category,book_click  WHERE  enable=1 AND category_id=7
AND books.book_id=book_category.book_id
ORDER BY  strong texttotal_views DESC GROUP BY books.book_id
```

**Original Answer:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT  books.book_id, url, title, short_desc, img, featured, SUM(views) as total_views
 FROM  books,book_category,book_click  WHERE  enable=1 AND category_id=7
AND books.book_id=book_category.book_id
ORDER BY  strong texttotal_views DESC GROUP BY your_grouping WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Example**

```
mysql> SELECT year, country, product, SUM(profit)
    -> FROM sales
    -> GROUP BY year, country, product WITH ROLLUP;
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| year | country | product    | SUM(profit) |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| 2000 | Finland | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | Finland | Phone      |         100 |
| 2000 | Finland | NULL       |        1600 |
| 2000 | India   | Calculator |         150 |
| 2000 | India   | Computer   |        1200 |
| 2000 | India   | NULL       |        1350 |
```